# Typo3 adds tt_content record id to header text

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm working with Typo3 v6.1 and when I add standard header block to the page, the block's id is being added to header's text body. Here are some screenshots:

**here is backend setting**
[image: back-end header form]

**and here is corresponding fron-end result**, note the element id `324`, which is added to the wrapper tag and to the tag content
[image: front-end result]

I'm trying to get rid of the id in the content. Id as attribute is desired and added by my TypoScript code

```
lib.stdheader.stdWrap.dataWrap.override = <header ... id="c{field:uid}">|</header>
```

But I have no idea who and where inserts the id to the content. I'm currently looking at `/typo3/sysext/css_styled_content/static/v6.0/setup.txt`
and trying to override some blocks of configuration related to headers, like `lib.stdheader` or `tt_content.header`, but whatever wrapper setting I change, my change only affects the "outer" html code, i.e. this added id is always inside that wrappers :(

Can someone help me spotting the appropriate rendering config or rendering function to debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the page where this occurs in the Web > Template module. Then select "TypoScript Object Browser" from the top menu.

Open the path "lib.stdheader".

Your problem must be within lib.stdheader.10 and lib.stdheader.20. Inspect these elements - you will see all configuration applied to it.

Comment: yep, that helped a lot. I was pretty sure that only my code affects the resulting config, but there were one more `TypoScript` file attached which was adding that id.